# Java's replace method not working

Tags: java, replace

I am trying to replace routeName and routeDurationInMinutes but the rpelace method is not working.  It was working when i had it outside the run function but inside it does not work.  Any ideas?  I have added all my code that I am trying to run.  Im sorry that this is so back and forth.  I tried to shorten it to make it easier for others to read.

```
The Value g =  {"routes":[{"routeName":"I-190 N; Electric Ave","routeDurationInMinutes":70,"routeLengthKM":83.865,"routeLengthMiles":52.111278915,"toll":false},{"routeName":"I-190 N; Greenville Rd","routeDurationInMinutes":82,"routeLengthKM":92.569,"routeLengthMiles":57.519692099000004,"toll":false}],"startPoint":"street address","endPoint":"destination","startLatitude":"42.20115054203528","startLongitude":"-71.85038140607858","endLatitude":"42.201220801535","endLongitude":"-71.849075146695"}

 final Runnable rundatapoll = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String g;
            try {
                g = new apicall().execute().get().getBody().toString();
                System.out.println(g);
                String route1;

                String route2;
                String time1;
                String time2;
                String time3;
                ArrayList parse= new ArrayList();
                ArrayList route= new ArrayList();
                ArrayList time= new ArrayList();
                Pattern p= Pattern.compile("routeName?.+?routeLengthKM");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(g);
                Pattern p2= Pattern.compile("routeName?.+?routeDurationInMinutes");
                Pattern p3= Pattern.compile("routeDurationInMinutes?.+?routeLengthKM");
                Matcher m3= p3.matcher(g);

                while (m.find()) {
                    parse.add(m.group());
                }

                while (m3.find()){
                    time.add(m3.group());
                }

                int l=0;
                while (l<parse.size()){
                    Matcher m2 =p2.matcher((CharSequence) parse.get(l));

                    while(m2.find()){
                        route.add(m2.group());
                    }

                    l++;
                }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                route1= (String) route.get(0);
                route2= (String) route.get(1);
                route1= route1.replace(",routeDurationInMinutes","");
                route1= route1.replace("routeName:","");
                route2= route2.replace(",routeDurationInMinutes","");
                route2= route2.replace("routeName:","");
                time1= (String) time.get(0);
                time2= (String) time.get(1);
                time1= time1.replace("routeDurationInMinutes:","");
                time1= time1.replace(",routeLengthKM","");
                time2= time2.replace("routeDurationInMinutes:","");
                time2= time2.replace(",routeLengthKM","");


                t1.setValue(time1);
                t2.setValue(time2);
                r1.setValue(route1);
                r2.setValue(route2);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

>>>routeName":"I-190 N; Electric Ave","routeDurationInMinutes
```

Comment: @tylerik do you ever execute the `Runnable`?

Comment: @tylerik Is this your true code? Because below you mentioned you altered it for the question. Let us see the real code that is being run.

Comment: Can you define "does not work" (`replace` method seems to be working fine for me http://ideone.com/sVD9Oc)

Comment: If I execute your posted code I get `I-190 N; Electric Ave` as output. What Java version (version, vendor, platform) do you use for compiling and executing?

Comment: ok sorry guys i will put the full code.  I was just trying to make it easy for everyone to read.

Comment: "I was just trying to make it easy for everyone to read" that was the right direction. Don't post your full code if it contains parts unrelated to your problem. Take your time and post minimal but complete (compilable) code example (it is worth to even start from scratch, I often find myself finding solution to a problem when I try to create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: Is that a JSON string (g)?

Comment: yes so it use the tostring to convert to string

Comment: You added more code, but it's still not a [minimal but complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows us to reproduce your problem (look at John's answer to see what a minimal but complete program looks like).  Please re-read Pshemo's comment.  He's 100% in the right.  If you try to do what he says, chances are very good that you will figure out the problem yourself in no time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the thread might not be being executed as suggested in the comments.

This worked for me:

```
package example;

public class Example {

     final String g="routeName:I-190 N; Electric Ave,routeDurationInMinutes";
     final Runnable rundatapoll = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  String route1=g;
                  System.out.println("BEFORE THREAD");
                  System.out.println(route1);
                  route1= route1.replace(",routeDurationInMinutes","");
                  route1= route1.replace("routeName:","");
                  System.out.println("AFTER RUNNING THREAD:");
                  System.out.println(route1);
                  System.out.println("DONE");
            }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        Thread thread = new Thread(example.rundatapoll);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
BEFORE THREAD
routeName:I-190 N; Electric Ave,routeDurationInMinutes
AFTER RUNNING THREAD:
I-190 N; Electric Ave
DONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a JSON parser.  Something like this:

```
package example;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String json = "{\"routes\":[{\"routeName\":\"I-190 N; Electric Ave\",\"routeDurationInMinutes\":70,\"routeLengthKM\":83.865,\"routeLengthMiles\":52.111278915,\"toll\":false},{\"routeName\":\"I-190 N; Greenville Rd\",\"routeDurationInMinutes\":82,\"routeLengthKM\":92.569,\"routeLengthMiles\":57.519692099000004,\"toll\":false}],\"startPoint\":\"street address\",\"endPoint\":\"destination\",\"startLatitude\":\"42.20115054203528\",\"startLongitude\":\"-71.85038140607858\",\"endLatitude\":\"42.201220801535\",\"endLongitude\":\"-71.849075146695\"}";
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
            JSONArray routes = (JSONArray) obj.get("routes");
            System.out.println("ROUTES: ");
            for(Object route : routes) {
                JSONObject routeObj = (JSONObject) route;
                String routeName = routeObj.get("routeName") + "";
                System.out.println("Route name: " + routeName);
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
ROUTES: 
Route name: I-190 N; Electric Ave
Route name: I-190 N; Greenville Rd
```